# How to validation check in Netsuite Suitelet Script

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I created form using nlapiCreateForm and add some fields.

Clicking submit button I want to check validation but it entered post mode automatically.

Some fields need to be required field so that null value couldn't be inputed.

Anyone pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your field, you can call `.setMandatory()`

Example:

```
var form = nlapiCreateForm('Test Form');
var field = form.addField('custpage_testfield','text','Test Field');
field.setMandatory(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

For all the client side validations you can create a new client side validation script for your dynamic form.

and then call

form.setScript('id of your client side script goes here');